# Form Fields: Title on top of the field?

Tags: html, css

How do I put the title on top of the form fields instead of on the side like on default?  Is there anyway to fix the code in CSS?

```
<label>Input Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputnumber" />
```

I don't want to use a break tag. That just adds more space between the title and the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/GsJhZ/)?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label for="inputnumber1">Input Number 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputnumber1" />
    <label for="inputnumber2">Input Number 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputnumber2" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
label {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS:

```
 <style type="text/css">
     label {
         display: block;
     }
 </style>
```

Or use a css class instead, if you want to break only some labels:

```
.block-label {
    display: block;
}
....
<label class="block-label">Input Number</label>
```

Comment: What happens if I want 2 fields next to each other on one line?  How do I put the titles on top?

Answer (score 0):

I put the 2  tags together instead and used the break tag to separate the  tags related.  Then adjusted the css spacing.  It worked marvelously.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:-

```
<label>Input Number</label>
<input type="text" id="inputnumber" />

label {
    display:block;
}
input {
    display:block;
}
```

### Update

You can achieve column layout in many ways:-

1) Using Floating Divs

#### Html

```
<div class="column">
    <label>Input Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputnumber" />
</div>
<div class="column">
    <label>Input Text</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputtext" />
</div>
```

#### Css

```
label {
    display:block;
}
input {
    display:block;
}
div.column
{
    float:left;
}
```

2) Using Table layout

#### Html

Same Html as above

#### Css

```
label {
    display:block;
}
input {
    display:block;
}
div.column
{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

3) Actual Tables

#### Html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label>Input Number</label>
        </th>
        <th>
            <label>Input Text</label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="text" id="inputnumber" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="text" id="inputtext" />
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That puts all the labels and inputs all to the left side. How do I put 2 fields side by side with the titles at the top.